# What is the interface for the modulo operator in ATS?

Tags: ats

What is the name of the integer modulo operator in ATS?
Also, given a positive integer p, does the typechecker know
that (x mod p) is a natural number less than p?

Comment: I post here a question asked by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use "%" and "mod" as the modulo operator in ATS
2. To make the compiler know this, you can construct something like

   ```
   datatype MOD (int, int) =
   | {i,j: int | i >=0 && j > 0 && i < j}
     MOD0(i, j) of ()
   | {i,j: int | i >=0 && j > 0 && i >= j}
     MOD1(i, j) of (MOD(i - j, j))

   (* ****** ****** *)

   prfun
   dmod
   {n,m:int | n >= 0 && m > 0}
   .<n>. 
   (i: int(n), j: int(m)) : MOD(n, m) =
     if i < j then MOD0()
     else MOD1(dmod(i - j, j))
   ```